# which code is used for form validation?

Tags: jquery, ajax

any jquery plugin path which is easy to use for form validation of each and every textfield of 
form.

```
enter code here <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action=""><table width="500" align="center">
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Please Add Bill Record</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="133">Number</td>
  <td width="355"><input type="text" name="number" id="number"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Amount</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>type</td>
  <td><label for="elc"></label>
    <select name="elc" id="elc" tabindex="3">
      <option>elecricity</option>
      <option>gas</option>
      <option>telephone</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
  <input type="reset" name="clear" id="clear" value="Clear" /></td>
</tr>
```

iwannt to validate every textfield of form on blur.how its easy by jquery .

Comment: For on blur validation, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622232/jquery-validation-onblur) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263984/jquery-on-blur-validation)

Answer (score 0):

[The jQuery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is the defacto validator for jQuery. Easy to set up, highly configurable. Seriously, it's the best there is :)

It's also one of the oldest jQuery plugins in existence and was written by one of the jQuery UI developers...

Answer (score 0):

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

It does everything you need.